# insert into 2column table, avoiding duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns, userid and messageid.  I am updating it automatically through a php script, but I can't get a working insert statement.  I don't mind if there are duplicates of userid, or duplicates of messageid (in fact there should be duplicates of both), I just don't want any duplicate of the same combination of userid and messageid.  Is there any way to write a query that will do this for me, or do I have to handle it at the php level?

I've probably tried 20 different queries that I found on here and google, but have not gotten it right.  This was the last thing I tried:

```
INSERT INTO interests_join (userid, interestid)
VALUES (1, 4)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT userid, interestid FROM interests_join WHERE userid = 1 AND interestid = 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `UNIQUE KEY`, sql will refuse to insert a new row that is a duplicate of an existing one.

```
ALTER TABLE `interests_join` ADD UNIQUE `row` (`userid`, `interestid`);
```

Then you'll have to check from PHP if the query was successful or not (error #1062). You can't apply the key if there are duplicate rows, you have to remove them first .

Comment: was hoping for a way to integrate this through a query rather than altering the table, but this gets the job done.